# If statement in c++, freaks out

Tags: c++, if-statement

when I try to run this game and wants to end it by typing "slut" or "Slut" (Swedish for 'end') it makes a new player call "slut" or "Slut" **BUT** when I only have ONE statement in the while loops or If statements it's all working. 
To make it more clear It works when I have *(playerName != "Slut")* but I want for safty have *(playerName != "Slut") || (playerName != "slut")* and then it wont work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

int main(){

```
//Declaration
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Swedish");           //Swedish characters
int dices;
int diceSum = 0;
int absoluteLowestSum = 999999999;      //To get out the lowest sum I'm comparing to a big value
int diceRoll1 = 0;
int diceRoll2 = 0;
string playerName;
string playerLost;
//Plants a seed
srand((int)time(0));
//Instructions
cout << "Nu spelar vi ”Otur i tärning”: " << endl;
cout << "Hur många tärningskast ska göras per spelare?" << endl;
cin >> dices;


//If "slut"/""Slut" is written, while stops
while ((playerName != "Slut") || (playerName != "slut")){
    cout << "Namnet på spelaren?";
    cin >> playerName;

    for (int i = 0; i < dices; i++){

        if ((playerName != "Slut") || (playerName != "slut")){

            diceRoll1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
            diceRoll2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
            cout << diceRoll1 << " " << diceRoll2 << " = " << diceRoll1 + diceRoll2 << endl;

            diceSum = diceSum + diceRoll1 + diceRoll2;




        }
    }

    if ((playerName != "Slut") || (playerName != "slut")){



        while (diceSum < absoluteLowestSum){        //Give us the lowest sum

            absoluteLowestSum = diceSum;
            playerLost = playerName;                    //Give us the name who lost

        }

        cout << "Summan: " << diceSum << endl;

        diceSum = 0;                                //Puts the sum to 0 when a new player enters his/her name

    }

    if ((playerName == "Slut") || (playerName == "slut")){



        cout << playerLost << " hade mest otur och fick tärningssumman " << absoluteLowestSum << endl;

    }


}




return 0;
```

}

Comment: The condition `(playerName != "Slut") || (playerName != "slut")` will *always* be **true**. If it is one, it cannot possibly be the other, so the complete eval will be true. If it is *neither* it is still true. Only if it were both *simultaneously* would it eval as false, which is impossible.

Comment: You need: `if ((playerName != "Slut") && (playerName != "slut")) `

Comment: Hmm so what do you suggest.. a bool?

Comment: I suggest you fix the logical expression as @BlueMoon described.

Comment: In what if statement? All 3 or?

Comment: This mistake stems from a misunderstanding of English and likely your native language. When you say "the player name _is not_ Slut _or_ slut" you're actually making a common error. You should say "the player name _is not_ Slut _and it is not_ slut" (which directly translates to the correct code), or "the player name _is neither_ Slut _nor_ slut" (which has no equivalent in code).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `&&` instead of `||`.Its supposed to be

```
if ((playerName != "Slut") && (playerName != "slut"))
```

And

```
while ((playerName != "Slut") && (playerName != "slut"))
```

in all the `if`s and `while` conditions having `!=` (`playerName != "Slut"` and `playerName != "slut"`)