# Program not recognizing character inputs in if-else statements

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, char, logical-operators

I debugged the program and discovered that although you enter an option, such as `Y/y/n/N` or `H/h/l/L`, the if functions can not recognize the inputs, and it skips over. Thanks for any advice! The RNG is working correctly, and everything seems to be fine to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>



 int main(){
char startAnswer[1];
char gameAnswer[1];
int i;
int r;
int t;
int compare;
srand(time(NULL));

printf("Do you want to play a game? Y/N. \n");
scanf(" %c", &startAnswer);
start:
if (startAnswer == 'y' || 'Y'){
    goto game;
}
else if (startAnswer == 'n' || 'N'){
    printf("Game will now exit.\n");
}
else {
    printf("You entered an invalid answer, try again.\n");
    goto start;
}
game:
printf("There will be ten numbers calculated.\n");
printf("Try to guess what the numbers are before\n");
printf("they are displayed. One at a time.\n\n");
for(i = 0; i < 12; i++){

    randGen:
    r = ( rand() % 9 ) + 1;
    t = ( rand() % 9 ) + 1;
    if(t == r){
        goto randGen;
    }

    printf("Is the next number higher or lower than %d\n\n" , r);
    scanf(" %c" , &gameAnswer);
 //ignore       (r > t) ? (compare = 0) : (compare = 1);
    if (r > t){
        compare = 1;
    }
    else{
        compare = 0;
    }



    if (gameAnswer == ('H' || 'h')){
        if (compare == 1){
            printf("You win this round!");
            goto randGen;
        }
    }
    else if (gameAnswer == ('L' || 'l')){
        if (compare == 0){
            printf("You win this round!");
            goto randGen;
        }
    }
    else if (gameAnswer != ('l' || 'L' || 'h' || 'H')){
        if (compare == 0){
            printf("Please Enter H/L for higher/lower answer.\n\n");
            goto randGen;
        }
    }
    else{
            printf("You lost this round.");
            goto randGen;
    }
    r = t;

}



}
```

Comment: Without your code we cannot help you at all.

Comment: this is not the correct way to ask question. please show us some code examples or what did you done yet.

Comment: please provide demo code which have this issue.

Comment: You don't quit the game when the user enters n/N.

Comment: Why do people keep assuming that the computer is magically "skipping over" their conditions?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should structure your program in a way to have less or even no `goto`s.

Comment: What is the point of char gameAnswer[1]?

Comment: Sorry for not having the code in the post at the start. New to stack. :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing user-inputted characters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911653/comparing-user-inputted-characters-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
if (gameAnswer == ('H' || 'h'))
```

does not do what you think it does. Change that to

```
if ((gameAnswer[0] == 'H')  || (gameAnswer[0] == 'h'))   //gameAnswer is an array
```

Similarly, for all other occurrences.

Also,

```
scanf(" %c", &startAnswer);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c", &startAnswer[0]);
```

and likewise

Note:

1. If you *don't need* an `array`, *don't use* one. Stick to a single variable.
2. The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.
3. Just a suggestion, please try avoiding `goto` statements. It's not considered a good practice. Try to write and use functions, instead.

Comment: @AlterMann Thank you, simply overlooked. Corrected. :-)

Comment: @farukdgn See, I can upvote your answer in the state it is now, but I want you to improve your answer. I'm not your enemy. :-)

Comment: @farukdgn if you _can_ believe me, I did not. I found out it while re-iteraing over the question, just like the latest edit. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the infom everyone. As you can tell I am still learning. I think making mistakes is essential to the learning process. I am revising my code now. Also, The only reason I used gotos was to just get it working. I know they are not a great way to do things.

Comment: All of this worked out for me. Thanks for explaining it. I had completely forgot I changed my variables into arrays and I remember going over how to chain conditions. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (startAnswer == 'y' || 'Y'){
```

No. This is not how to chain conditions. [You are translating broken English into C++.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957807/if-statement-in-c-freaks-out#comment40642903_25957807)

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues:

One of them is:

```
char startAnswer[1];
char gameAnswer[1];
```

which shoule be

```
char startAnswer;
char gameAnswer;
```

Your compiler certainly issued a warning here.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your code:

1. the `if` conditions, like this one: `if (gameAnswer == ('H' || 'h'))`, which should have been: `if (gameAnswer == 'H' || gameAnswer=='h')`
2. The `chars`: `char startAnswer[1]; char gameAnswer[1];` Either do this: `char startAnswer; char gameAnswer;` or: use `gameAnswer[0]` instead of `gameAnswer` in your code.

Lastly, for `srand` and `rand`, you need to include the `stdlib` library, just add this line : `#include<stdlib.h>`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/

Answer (score -1):

Are you using `fflush(stdin)` before read the option? This will clean up your buffer.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, to clean up the buffer use `int c; while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);`