# If statement running even when not true

Tags: c++

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here, every time I run it, it goes through the `if` part even when it's not true? So the 'else' never runs.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string choice;
float numb;

float convert(float numb,string choice)
{
    float newNo;
    if (choice == "F" or "f"){
        newNo = numb * 0.2 * 9 + 32;
    }else{
        newNo = (numb - 32) / 1.8;
    }
    return newNo;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "welcome to Temperature converter v0.1" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Which conversion would you like to use?" << endl;
    cout << "type C to convert to Celsius and F to convert to Fahrenheit - ";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << "what number would you like to convert? - ";
    cin >> numb;

    cout << convert(numb,choice);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (choice == "F" or "f"){` doesn't do what you think it does. Write valid C++ syntax to get expected behaviour from your code.

Comment: As @πάντα ῥεῖ said, you misunderstand the syntax and meaning of the symbols in the "if"-statement. You need to read up on comparissions and operator precedence. Hint, "f" is always true.

Comment: the `==` operator comes before the `or` operator, so it is the same like `if ((choice == "F") or ("f"))`. the string `"f"`, evaluated as a boolean, is always true, because it is not the NULL pointer (maybe not explained perfectly, but more or less)

Comment: _"it goes through the IF part even when its not true?"_ No it doesn't. So your debugging should have focused on "why is this true"? And then you'd have found out your mistake.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957807/if-statement-in-c-freaks-out#comment40642903_25957807)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your `if` Statement:

```
if (choice == "F" or "f"){
```

basically, what you say here is:
If choise is "F" or if "f". You need to understand: True is everything besides zero (`0`). `"f"` is NOT zero, so it is true. You could also wirte (`or` = `||`):

```
if (coice == "F" || true)
```

which is the same like:

```
if (true)
```

So in order for your code to work, you need:

```
if (choice == "f" || choice == "F")
```

That would do what you expect.

Comment: thank you very much! im still so new to this so, maybe I should learn more before asking again, thank you.

Comment: There are no stupid questions. As long as you show some effort and have a problem in the code, everything is fine to be asked here. Even if its a beginners question. Just dont state "do work for me" questions...

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem in the syntax of 'if' statement. Following is the corrected code, where '||' stands for 'or':

```
if ((choice == "F") || (choice=="f")){
    newNo = numb * 0.2 * 9 + 32;
}else{
    newNo = (numb - 32) / 1.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this if statement

```
if (choice == "F" or "f"){
```

to the following

```
if (choice == "F" or choice == "f"){
```

Otherwise the right operand of the operator `or`

```
"f"
```

is always equal to true because it is converted to the address of the first character of the string literal that evidently is not equal to 0.

That is your original condition in the if statement looks like

```
if (choice == "F" or "f" != nullptr){
```

and indeed `"f" != nullptr`